# Bash script, cleanup steps.

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

Hi I have a bash script that performs some file operations, as the last steps of the script I issue some cleanup commands that must be executed.

The problem is that If the script is somehow manually terminated (using cmd-z etc) these final steps do not get executed and then have to be done manually. Is there a way to ensure such actions? something like the finally block of exception handling. Sample code follows

```
#rename a folder ($1 being a parameter passed to the script)
mv ../project/game ../project/$1
# perform some steps within the new folder
....
# now comes the cleanup part
mv ../project/$1 ../project/game
```

This script gets executed a lot of time by many team members to switch and manage their environemnts and for the most time works flawlessly. The problem happens when the script is terminated halfway through before the cleanup is done and the renamed folders and files break the script from execution again.

Is there anything that can be done here to fix this?

Comment: use the `trap` command. Examples here: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can trap signals

`trap finally SIGINT`

Where finally is some function. That will not make your script immune to `SIGKILL` though as it is "untrapable"

See http://linux.die.net/Bash-Beginners-Guide/sect_12_02.html

Comment: Trapping signals has saved my day multiple times, +1 for supplying the link.

Comment: Trapping EXIT pseudo signal with cleanup code is probably a better idea.

Comment: @Basilevs Thats probably true, yes!